# Admob "The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.ads.AdView" for Admob 6.0.1 running 2.3.3

Tags: android, class, admob, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a 2.3.3 android app that I am developing that I would like to add Admob ads onto. The admob ads version is 6.0.1. I follow the directions on googles site to add it and it does not seem to work properly for 2.3.3, and assumed working correctly for 4.0.3. I am developing against for the goal of releasing a 2.3.3 version to support Blackberry playbook and most android devices out there.

When I add everything to the android manifest, with the added being:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

With the build path external jar pointing to the android adk path to google admob then the jar in there and then adding this to the XML file:

Up top:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

And down in the XML layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adUnitId="I put my id here"
                             ads:adSize="BANNER"
                             ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
                             ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

It comes up with the error on the graphical layout on the 2.3.3 gui designer stating:

"The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details."

When I open the class it says it cant see the source.

If I change the GUI designer to be 4.0.3 (as you need to target this apparently to compile) then the admob shows up in a black box and seems ok. I need it working for 2.3.3 though and I seem to crash instantly now when I load this app in the 2.3.3 emulator.

Any help? I read that this should be able to be used in 2.3.3 so I don't understand why. I had a libs folder but I took it out and just externally references the JAR.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are externally referencing the jar, you'll need to go to the "Order and Export" tab in the Java Build Path and explicitly export the AdMob SDK jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

It was all correct, but it is a bug on why it does not show in the WYSIWYG editor.

When run on the emulator or a device, the ads show.