# com.google.ads.AdView could not be instantiated?

Tags: java, android, class, admob, adview

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

getting this error in graphic layout:
I did all the necessary things required for setting an ad , like adding jar, wrote in manifest as well.
I know I,m posting duplicate question but I cant understand it.

[Admob "The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.ads.AdView" for Admob 6.0.1 running 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035340/admob-the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-com-google-ads-adview)

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you sure you have added the Admob jar to your IDE classpath (it doesn't sound like you have)?

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

under

```
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

at the beginning of the xml layout file